# Allocating equal plot space to all of multiple plots with shared axes

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to tile plots, specifically in a 2x3 matrix, for example:

```
x <- seq(1, 10, by=.01)
y <- 1/x

prms<-
  list(xlab=rep(c("", "x"), each=3),
       ylab=rep(c("y", "", ""), 2),
       xaxt=rep(c("n", "s"), each=3),
       yaxt=rep(c("s", "n", "n"), 2),
       mar=list(c(0  , 4.1, 4.1,   0),
                c(0  ,   0, 4.1,   0),
                c(0  ,   0, 4.1, 1.1),
                c(5.1, 4.1,   0,   0),
                c(5.1,   0,   0,   0),
                c(5.1,   0,   0, 1.1)))

par(mfrow=c(2, 3))
for (ii in 1:6){
  par(mar=prms$mar[[ii]])
  plot(x, y, type="l", lwd=2,
       xlab=prms$xlab[ii], ylab=prms$lab[ii],
       xaxt=prms$xaxt[ii], yaxt=prms$yaxt[ii])
}
```

Which produces:

[image: A plot suffering from the problem described. The plot is a 2x3 panel of the same "l" curve repeated. The intention is for all 6 plots to occupy roughly the same "visual real estate", but in this output, the first column is "squeezed" and the 2nd column takes the plurality of space.]

I've suppressed the "inner" margins and axes because all `x` (resp., `y`) units are the same, so such axes would be redundant. However, as you can see, by squeezing the margins on the left- and rightmost plots, I've accidentally given the middle plots too much space (it's not as apparent, but the same trouble plagues the top vis-a-vis the bottom row).

Therein lies the conundrum. `mfrow` assigns equal space to each *subplot* (i.e., axes, margins, etc), not to each plot area. How can I change my approach so that each plotting area is of equal size, *ceteris paribus* (i.e., axes, etc. unchanged)? I thought of using `layout`, but couldn't think of a nice programmatic way to go about making sure everything has equal representation.

Comment: I strongly prefer a `base` approach for consistency with other plots in this project, but `ggplot` (etc) solutions could be instructive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may set `mar` to 0, and use `oma` to give the size of the outer margins. Axes are added to relevant plots in a loop. Common x and y axis labels are added with `mtext` and `outer = TRUE`

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 3),
    mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
    oma = c(4, 4, 0.5, 0.5))

for (i in 1:6) {
  plot(x, y, type = "l", axes = FALSE)
  if (i %in% c(4, 5, 6))
    axis(side = 1)
  if (i %in% c(1, 4))
    axis(side = 2)
  box()
  }

mtext("x values", side = 1, outer = TRUE, line = 2.5)
mtext("y values", side = 2, outer = TRUE, line = 2.5)
```

[image]

See also [How to create multiple plots, each with same plot area size, when only one plot has axis labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572341/how-to-create-multiple-plots-each-with-same-plot-area-size-when-only-one-plot)

Comment: It's a shame there's no way to say something like `axis(side=if(i%%3==1)2)` to make this more concise, but anyway this is great! learned a lot, e.g. `box` is nice to know.

Comment: For now, using this function: `tile_axes<-function(n,M,N,...){
  if (n>(M-1)*N)do.call("axis",c(side=1,list(...))); 
  if (n%%N==1)do.call("axis",c(side=2,list(...)))}`

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thank you for your feedback. Good that you found a way to avoid hardcoding of the index of plots which should have axis!

Comment: Just a quick update that I changed `...` in that function (which I've added to my little [package](https://github.com/MichaelChirico/funchir) of such functions) to `params` which accepts a `list` of two `lists` to allow passing different parameters to x and y axes (i.e., `c(side = 1, params[[1]])` for x axis parameters, `c(side = 2, params[[2]])` for y).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! Looks really nice. Good luck with your package.